# Extra content at the end of the document PHP and XML

Tags: php, xml

I having a strange problem when I'm trying to produce an XML file with PHP. The problems is that, a strange question mark appears at the end of the source code. And I get the error: "Extra content at the end of the document"

I'm running this script:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/xml");
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>";
?>

<Module>
      <ModulePrefs title="Ngram Extractor"
        author="interedition team"
       description="Ngram Extractor"
        scrolling="true"/>
        <Content type="html">
        Test
        </Content>
</Module>​
```

When I open this is a browser, I get the state error and the source code looks like this. Notice the strange question mark at the end.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Module>
      <ModulePrefs title="Ngram Extractor"
        author="interedition team"
       description="Ngram Extractor"
        scrolling="true"/>
        <Content type="html">
        Test
        </Content>
</Module>?
```

Please help.

Comment: spurious echo somewhere in your code, or text that isn't enclosed in <?php ?> tags

Comment: The strange character is probably present att he end of your source file, or generated because you're not ending the XML in the source file with a line feed.

Comment: how do I end the XML with a line feed?

Comment: in general, it doesn't seem like the browser is even recognizing this an xml document? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @Jpsy well that's good to know and also makes my problem even more strange :)

Comment: I have removed my comment and posted an answer below. My first test did not show any question marks or errors, but my browser (Chrome & IE9) also did not recognize the output as XML. This brought me onto the right track.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a *zero width space* character at the end of your file - UTF-8 code E2 80 8B. It is placed right after `</Module>`. Have a look at your file in hex mode.
This extra character prevents your browser from recognizing this as valid XML and - depending on the browser in use - shows up as a question mark or does not show up at all.

Remove that extra character and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

May be you use UTF-8 with BOM encoding. Check it

Comment: @Jeff you can check it in notepad++ editor. "Encoding" in main menu

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have answer, accept that my editor wasn't showing the question mark. But one I opened the file in notepad2, lo and behold, the question mark was there. Very strange. Thanks for your help.

Comment: As said in my response above: This question mark was an invisible UTF-8 character. It even made it into the copy of your code here at StackOverflow - although it cannot be seen (not even in HTML code view). But when copied into a Hex editor the UTF-8 code E2 80 8B shows up at the end of your code.