# Not well-formed error at the end

Tags: php, xml

As you can see I tries to make a very simple XML example with PHP. My problem is that at the end, at `</users>` I get an XML Parsing Error: not well-formed and I do not understand why since I do not use any special characters or any URLs. Does anyone have any ideas what the problem might be?

[image: parsing error]

```
<?php 
    header('Content-type: text/xml');

    $xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\n";
    $xml .= "<users>\n";
    $xml .= "test\n";
    $xml .="</users>";
    echo $xml;
?>
```

Comment: It's working for me, a well formated XML!

Comment: I can't replicate this. Is this definitely all of the code?

Comment: Works for me too.

Comment: another good way of acheiving what you want maybe by using **simplexml** check this answer here ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486757/how-to-generate-xml-file-dynamically-using-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. The solution was posted in this thread: [Extra content at the end of the document PHP and XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850120/extra-content-at-the-end-of-the-document-php-and-xml)

In short, I had to open the file with HexEdit and delete some characters.